# How get Messages Behind value of Consumer group in Kafka by using python

Tags: python, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Is it possible to get "Messages Behind" value in Kafka consumer group by using python?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, `kafka-python` has functions for querying high watermark of a topic and a current consumer group's committed position. The difference of these gives you the "messages behind", otherwise called lag.