# high watermark of a topic

Tags: python, apache-kafka

About OneCricketeer's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74027900/how-get-messages-behind-value-of-consumer-group-in-kafka-by-using-python),, I can get consumer group offsets using  [KafkaAdminClient.list_consumer_group_offsets](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html#kafka.KafkaAdminClient.list_consumer_group_offsets). But how can I query high watermark of a topic?

I read kafka-python documentation, but i didn't find how get high watermark of a topic.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), [what are you asking], and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), and provide a [mre]. **DO NOT** post images of code, links to code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that there isn't functionality on [`KafkaAdminClient`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaAdminClient.html) to obtain the high water offset.

However, the [`KafkaConsumer`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html) has a method called [`highwater(partition)`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.highwater) that will return an integer offset for the [`TopicPartition`](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/blob/f19e4238fb47ae2619f18731f0e0e9a3762cfa11/kafka/structs.py#L13) provided.

The `TopicPartition` is a named tuple composed of the topic (`str`) and a partition ID (`int`).

You can use [`KafkaConsumer.partitions_for_topic(topic)`](https://kafka-python.readthedocs.io/en/master/apidoc/KafkaConsumer.html#kafka.KafkaConsumer.partitions_for_topic) to obtain a set of partition IDs for the provided topic.  You can then combine those with the topic name to create the required `TopicPartition` objects needed for `KafkaConsumer.highwater()`.

A simple proof of concept might look like the following:

```py
results = {}

topic_partitions = [TopicPartition("topic_name", partition_id) for partition_id in consumer.partitions_for_topic()]

for topic_partition in topic_partitions:
    results[topic_partition] = consumer.highwater(partition)
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, Philip Wrage.

For my purpose (get messages behind for a given consumer group ) I found that method end_offsets is better.

Here my solution:

```py
from kafka import KafkaAdminClient, KafkaConsumer
from icecream import ic

bootstrap_servers=['boostrapserver001:9092',
    'boostrapserver002:9092', 
    'boostrapserver003:9092']

consumer_group = "my-consumer-group"

kafkaAdminClient = KafkaAdminClient(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers)

offsets = kafkaAdminClient.list_consumer_group_offsets(consumer_group)
consumer = KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers=bootstrap_servers)

end_offsets = consumer.end_offsets(offsets.keys())

for partition in offsets:
    ic(offsets[partition])
    ic(end_offsets[partition])
```

### Environment

```
$ python -V
Python 3.11.3
```

```
$ pip freeze
asttokens==2.2.1
colorama==0.4.6
executing==1.2.0
icecream==2.1.3
kafka-python==2.0.2
Pygments==2.15.1
six==1.16.0
```